# Some devise messages are not shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I cannot figure out why most of the devise flash messages work, but `unlocks.send_instructions` is not shown when an account is locked. Also, `failure.locked` and `failure.last_attempt` are not shown, even though I have it configured to warn on the last attempt. The only message ever displayed is `failure.invalid`, when the account is unlocked, when it gets locked and after it has been locked. I have combed through the Devise source and I cannot figure out why this is happening. I have Devise 3.3.0 installed and I am on Rails 4.1.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't realize that the paranoid setting would disable all messages besides the invalid email/password message. That is the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Using-paranoid-mode,-avoid-user-enumeration-on-registerable There is some information about it. Glad I helped you!