# Displaying failure messages using Devise gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Hello 
 I have a problem with displaying Devise failure messages. No matter what I do, I always get the "invalid" message even though the account is locked. My goal is to display the "locked" message for 10 minutes after 5 failed attempts.

The gem is configured properly because accounts are being locked correctly. The only problem I have is with the messages.

This is my code from the devise.rb file, which is related to the lockable module:

```
  config.paranoid = false
  config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts
  config.unlock_keys = [:time]
  config.unlock_strategy = :time
  config.maximum_attempts = 5
  config.unlock_in = 10.minutes
  config.last_attempt_warning = true
```

I found other topics on stackoverflow (e.g. [Some devise messages are not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147438/some-devise-messages-are-not-shown), [Devise: lockable - last_attempt_warning not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698096/devise-lockable-last-attempt-warning-not-displaying)), where people say it's because of the paranoid mode, that's why I disabled it, but it still doesn't solve my issue. Devise does not seem to display any other message than "invalid" no matter what I put in the Devise config file (last_attempt_warning isn't showing up as well).

This is part of devise.en.yml related to failures:

```
en:  
  devise:
   failure:
    already_authenticated: "You are already logged in."
    deactivated: "Your account is no longer active. Please contact your administrator for access."
    inactive: "Your account is not activated yet."
    invalid: "Sorry, the email or password you entered is incorrect."
    last_attempt: "You have one more attempt before your account will be locked."
    locked: "Your account has been locked. Try to log in again in 5 minutes."
    not_found_in_database: "Sorry, the email or password you entered is incorrect."
    timeout: "Your session expired. Please log in again to continue."
    unauthenticated: "You need to log in or sign up before continuing."
    unconfirmed: "You have to confirm your account before continuing."
```

I tried to workaround it by creating a method in Sessions Controller:

```
before_action :check_failed_attempts, only: :create
def check_failed_attempts
  flash.clear

  email = params["educator"]["email"]
  return unless email

  user = Person.find_by(email: email)
  return unless user

  if user.access_locked?
    flash[:alert] = I18n.t "devise.failure.locked"
  end
end
```

but devise seems to override the flash[:alert] and displays the invalid message anyway.

I spent a few hours trying to fix it and run out of ideas already, so I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not halting the request cycle in your `before_action`, so the request is proceeding to call the `create` action which is overriding the `flash[:alert]`. From the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters):

> If a "before" filter renders or redirects, the action will not run. If
> there are additional filters scheduled to run after that filter, they
> are also cancelled.

```
def check_failed_attempts
  flash.clear

  email = params["educator"]["email"]
  return unless email

  user = Person.find_by(email: email)
  return unless user

  if user.access_locked?
    flash[:alert] = I18n.t "devise.failure.locked"
    redirect_to new_educator_session_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome. That works for me. One additional question. Any ideas why the default functionality of Devise doesn't work? Ideally, I'd like to get rid of this method and just rely on Devise to show up the locked message.

Comment: @BartoszChodyła not from a first glance. The only thing that is out of place is `config.unlock_keys = [:time]`. The value is usually `:email` as it is used to find the user ([Source code](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/5d5636f03ac19e8188d99c044d4b5e90124313af/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb#L180)) but I don't believe this method is called in the sessions controller

Comment: I took it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184514/how-to-lock-users-using-devise 
I belive it's standard configuration when `config.unlock_strategy = :time`